# Build a treeview in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview

I am trying to build a three level treeview in WPF. Basically, I have a list of top level items that all have one more child items. Those child item may or may not have themselves chid items.

Anyone know of a tutorial available on the net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use bindings and [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate). Declare a class with your data :

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public event PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

And define a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for this type :

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Item}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Now you just need to bind the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView` to your collection of top-level items, and the tree nodes will be constructed automatically. If you need to add (or remove) a node, just add an item to (or remove it from) the parent collection

For this example, I used a single item type, but if you have several types to display in the `TreeView` you will need to define a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for each. For leaf nodes (nodes with no children), you can just use a regular `DataTemplate`

Comment: If you omit the fact that I don't declare the DataType and that Header doesn't seem to exist, I was able to make it work with different objects with more then one type. the displayed date have the same property name so it worked.
It might not be the best way, but since the display has to be simple, I will do it like this for now.

Comment: Indeed there was an error in my code, the Header property doesn't exist... it's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

This example may be what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Comment: I realize this is 4 years old but it's worth saying... Amen to that. WPF tutorials across the net are horribly complicated. The farther I go the more I see, I don't think that half the people writing tutorials really knew what they were doing. Things in WPF don't have to be THAT complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late for your problem, but somebody who is running into same problem.
I found a very good free Control for WPF: [DW.WPFToolkit](http://www.my-libraries.de/index.php/librariesoverview/7-dwwpftoolkit)
With a good documentation..