# WPF TreeListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, tree, treelistview

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use the `TreeListView` in WPF/XAML/Expression Blend. Without using the code behind.

This what I want to do. I would like to populate a `TreeListView` with information, if the information's client and matter are the same, then just make that item a child of it.

Example:

Client 1= Kevin, Matter = Cook, Time =5
Client 2 = John, Matter = Program, Time = 4
Client 3 = Sam, Matter = Run, Time =9
Client 4 = Kevin, Matter = Cook, Time=7

The problem will look like this
the - and + is the expansion of the tree list view

```
- Kevin Cook 5
       Kevin Cook 7
  John Program 4
  Sam Run 9
```

I am retrieving all the information from a database. My current problem is, I can't add a children into my treelist. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this without hard coding?
 I looked into the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but there was not much information in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: it's TreeListView, its like ListView Combined with TreeListView

Answer (score 0):

.. and does this link help?

[Build a treeview in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473566/build-a-treeview-in-wpf)

OK.. so can you arrange your data in exactly the hierarchical manner that you want to view it.

Like, we have a collection of all the "unique" entries (client and matter are unique). All these unique entries will have other "duplicate" entries (matching client and matter).

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the objects similiar to entitySource and configure the datasource of the object to know how to apply that data.