# WPF - Create Treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have list of type field that can represent a hierarchy: List MyFields

```
public class Field
{
    public Field(string name, string value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IList<Field> SubFields { get; set; }
}
```

How can i bind MyFields to a TreeView?

EDIT: 
I forgot, i want to eg. show the value in a message box when clicking on the item.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build a treeview in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473566/build-a-treeview-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2):

Set the TreeViews ItemsSource to the Property you want to bind with.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) which should be placed in the resources of your TreeView or at an higher level, make sure to set the `DataType` to your class to make it apply.

Something like this for example:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Field}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SubFields}">
    <ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </ContentControl>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Field field = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Field;
    MessageBox.Show(field.Value.ToString());
}
```

You also need a root-elements list to which you can bind the `ItemsSource` of the TreeView itself.