# WPF - I'm stumped on the TreeView control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Pun intended.

I want to create a simple TreeView using the HierarchicalDataTemplate class.

Here's my problem XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider 
        x:Key="myDataProvider"
        ObjectType="vm:ContractViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataProvider}" Path="Contract" />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel
    Orientation="Vertical"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox MinWidth="400" Margin="10"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Commissions}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TreeView>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Contract}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Commissions}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

I'm using the MVVM pattern. The StaticResource "myDataProvider" returns an instance of a Contract (custom) class. Here's my model:

```
internal class Contract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Commission> Commissions { get; set; }
}

internal class Commission
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

FYI - my model is actually more complex; my classes contain more members than shown, they have constructors, and they implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

In my test, I load two Commission objects into a Contract object. The listbox works as expected: I can see the Id of each Commission object w/in Contract. The TreeView doesn't work: it returns a "System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate" string in the TreeView control where I'd expect each Commission Id to be listed.

I've referred to [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473566/build-a-treeview-in-wpf/1473617#1473617) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to no avail. I'd be appreciative of your help!

Comment: What if you change your `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />` to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />`.  Tell us about some binding errors you might be seeing in Console.

Comment: Same result; it returns a "System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate" string in the TreeView control. I don't see any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell is that you're not using the `TreeView` correctly in XAML. You need to put your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` at the `TreeView.Resources` level and assign a `ItemsSource`

As shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) you want to set the Template of the item.

Try to do something like this instead:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Contracts}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Contract}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Commissions}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Commission}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I personally do it like this--using RadTreeView:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BaseType}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this doesn't completely fix my problem. I'll post a follow up question.

Comment: You should specify `DataType="{x:Type m:Commission}" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"`, then you should add another HiearchicalDataTemplate for x:Type m:Product I believe.

Comment: Hi, NETscape. If you care to try and answer my follow up question, it's here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735680/wpf-treeview-databinding-follow-up)