# WPF TreeView databinding follow up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

As a follow up to my [first TreeView question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714846/wpf-im-stumped-on-the-treeview-control/21731485#21731485), I'm unable to bind a TreeView control to the Id property of my Commission object *and* its Products collection in the same TreeView control. 
Here's my simplified model:

```
internal class Contract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Commission> Commissions { get; set; }
}

internal class Commission
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

internal class Product
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my problem XAML. Contract returns a collection of Commission objects (Commissions). I've commented out the HierarchicalDataTemplate for returning Products. Either HierarchicalDataTemplate will work individually, but not if both are uncommented:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Contract.Commissions}">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Commission}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
                    <!--<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Commission}" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>-->
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                </TreeView>
```

If both HierarchicalDataTemplates are uncommented, an error is thrown because I'm using a unique (Commission Type) twice, but I don't know how to make either HierarchicalDataTemplate work without using Commission Type as the template's DataType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are jumbling up things here. I assume you want to show Commission's Id and beneath each Commission node, child Product's code value.

Only one `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of Commission is required and one `DataTemplate` for Product:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Commission}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Product}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
   </DataTemplate> 
</TreeView.Resources>
```

**Explanation**:

- Declare `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for nodes which needs to contain child nodes. In your case Commission.
- Set `ItemsSource` to child collection which you need to shown beneath those nodes. In your case `Products`.
- Lastly, declare `DataTemplate` for node which won't contain any child nodes. In your case Product.

Comment: Great answer and I love the explanation! Thanks!